# convert a Kmeans to a Raster Layer

Tags: r, gis, cluster-computing, k-means, raster

I have a problem .
I have a tiff image and I have made a Kmeans on it, the resulting file is a large Kmeans and I need to transform it back to RasterLayer in order to load it into a GIS. Any solution?

```
Biomasaencina<-raster("C:/Users/34600/Documents/dehesa.tif")

bio <-stack(Biomasaencina)
v <- getValues(bio)
k <- which(!is.na(v))
v <- na.omit(v)

#Kmeans
kmncluster<-kmeans(v,
                   centers= 2,
                   iter.max= 10,
                   nstart=2,
                   algorithm="Lloyd",
                   trace = FALSE)

#Convert to raster
kmeans_raster1 <- raster(Biomasaencina)

kmeans_raster1 <- setValues(Biomasaencina,kmncluster$cluster)
Error in setValues(Biomasaencina, kmncluster$cluster):length(values) is not equal to ncell(x), or to 1

writeRaster(kmeans_raster,filename = "k_means_dehesas",
            format("GTiff"),
            overwrite=TRUE)
```